# Installation of Python on Linux Server

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, unix, oraclelinux

I am trying to install Python 3.9.4 on my Linux machine (Oracle Linux 7.5). Python 2.7.5 is already present. Please let me know the detailed steps to do this as I am not get proper steps anywhere.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are no plans to update OL7 beyond its current versions.  Python 3.6.8 is available in the EPEL repo (https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) but to have 3.9.4 you'll have to get it from the python webpage (https://www.python.org) directly.